# Bug tracking software with a win32/web interface

Tags: bug-tracking

Can someone recommend bug tracking software with the following requirements:

- open source
- has a web and a windows forms interface.
- written in java or c#

these requirements are not a must but nice to have:

- system can run on linux system (at least the db/backend)
- can integrate with svn
- integration with project management software (project management software suggestions would be welcome)

Comment: Why in the world do you care if your bug tracking application is written in C# or Java?

Comment: Also, this question might be more appropriate for pm.stackexchange.com

Comment: Because we dev in c#/java, so if any custom dev needs to be done, we can do it

Comment: Wow, there were bullets in there. Totally missed that part. You have to put a space between the dash and the first letter in order for the markdown to recognize them as bullets. I've already fixed your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is fairly common bug tracking system with a web interface and plugins to integrate it with Eclipse-Mylyn tasks.

It also integrates well with svn. There are possibilities to link tickets (bug reports) to svn commits etc.